# Remove button added by a tinymce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tinymce, filtering

I want to hide the link options button shown in tinymce plugin (wpload), the one that shows up when clicking "Link" button..

Is there any call like

tinymce.PluginManager.get('pluginName').removeButton(...) ?

More specifically I want to remove Link Options from wplink plugin tinymce version 4.5.6. I saw this call in the plugin code, wonder how I can remove it from my custom WP plugin (dont want to hack the wplink plugin itself)?

```
            editor.addButton( 'wp_link_advanced', {
                    tooltip: 'Link options',
                    icon: 'dashicon dashicons-admin-generic',
                    onclick: function() {
                            if ( typeof window.wpLink !== 'undefined' ) {
            ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a WP plugin and use the `mce_buttons` hook to change the list of toolbar buttons that the editor will load.

It would look something like this:

```
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'remove_link_button', 2000);

function remove_link_button( $buttons ) {
  // Remove the toolbar button for the link plugin
  $remove = array('link');

  return array_diff( $buttons, $remove );
}
```

I would note that this would note fully remove the link plugin's functionality - it would just remove that toolbar button.  The plugin also has right click functionality on links so if you want all the functionality gone you also need to use the `tiny_mce_before_init` hook to remove the plugin from the list of plugins to be loaded.

*Note:  There are lots of examples of how to create a WP plugin so I am not going to repeat them here ... the code above would need to go into a WordPress plugin to function properly in WordPress.*